# cnn news webscraper return empty [] without information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

so i wrote this code for now:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re


serch_term = input('What News are you looking for today? ')

url = f'https://edition.cnn.com/search?q={serch_term}'
page = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

page_text = doc.find_all('<h3 class="cnn-search__result-headline">')
print(page_text)
```

but im getting empty [] as an result if i print(page_text) does someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- content is provided dynamically by `JavaScript`, so you wont get it with `requests`
- We do not know your search term, maybe there are no results
- `BeautifulSoup` is not working with something like `<h3 class="cnn-search__result-headline">` as selection.

How to fix? Use [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/) that works like a browser, renders also `JavaScript` and could provide you the `page_source` as expected.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://edition.cnn.com/search?q=python')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser' )
soup.select('h3.cnn-search__result-headline')
```

#### Output

```
[<h3 class="cnn-search__result-headline">
 <a href="//www.cnn.com/travel/article/airasia-malaysia-snake-plane-rerouted-intl-hnk/index.html">AirAsia flight in Malaysia rerouted after snake found on board plane</a>
 </h3>,
 <h3 class="cnn-search__result-headline">
 <a href="//www.cnn.com/2021/11/19/cnn-underscored/athleta-gift-shop-holiday/index.html">With gift options under $50 plus splurge-worthy seasonal staples, Athleta's Gift Shop is a holiday shopping haven</a></h3>,...]
```

---

To get the title call the `.text` methode while iterating your `ResultSet` and to grab the value of `href` use `['href']` on its contained `<a>`